# cannot log into Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS after startup

Tags: 12.04, boot, dell, freeze, inspiron

I recently installed 64bit Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on my Inspiron 1720 laptop as a dual-boot with Windows 7.

When I boot up Ubuntu, it gets to the log in screen just fine but after logging in it gets stuck with the default desktop background display only. I can move the cursor around but I can't get any response from it. No response from any keyboard commands or from any clicking and I eventually have to force it off.

I can log in recovery mode just fine without any issue so I've updated Ubuntu in recovery mode but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution but try this:

- Log into your desktop and wait until the hard drive stop reading. The way you describe it seems like unity is not loading properly.
- After this, switch and  log into a tty. You can do this pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and log into the terminal.
- Change the variable DISPLAY so the next commands will affect the graphic environment:

  `export DISPLAY=:0.0`
- Execute this:

  `compiz --replace &`
- This should make compiz try to restart. You should return to the GUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd>) and see if it loads the desktop. Any error message would show up in the tty6 you executed the command.
- If this doesn't work, try to reset unity to defaults, in the same tty6:

  `unity --reset`
- And repeat the process, try to reload compiz/unity again and see if it works. As a last advice if this is not working you could install an alternative desktop manager like gnome-shell or xfce:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

That way you'll have at least an usable desktop to surf the web and search the answer. It may be a problem with your graphic drivers and after installing them it may work. What graphic card are you using? I remember having a lot of problems with ATI cards...

Wish it helps, good luck!

Comment: Tried all the options, didn't seem to do fix the issue so I continued to log in and use Ubuntu through recovery mode. Tried to log in regular recently and it works fine now. Not sure why but I assume what you suggested helped so thank you. I have an NVIDIA graphics card.